# fastest way to split a large list

Tags: python, list, date, datetime, filter

I have a list of DOY data. The list is almost 900,000 entries long. The issue I'm having is that the data initially goes up to 365, but then starts at 1 again, when I would like it to go past 365. For example:

```
>>> continue_list([140, 141, 145, 270, 365, 365.90, 1, 2, 5, 360])
>>> [140, 141, 145, 270, 365, 365.90, 366, 367, 370, 725]
```

Here's my try:

```
def continue_list(x):
    l = []
    m = []
    for i in x:
        if math.floor(i) == 1:
            l = l+ x[x.index(i):]
            l = list(map(lambda x: x+365, l))
            m = m + x[:x.index(i)]
            new_x = m + l
    return new_x
```

This works for small lists perfectly. But for a list with 900,000 entries, it's not feasible; my computer crashes immediately. Any tips on a faster approach?

Comment: I'm not clear where the "split" comes in or how you get your expected output; what is supposed to happen if you go through several annual cycles, how do you account for the total number of days to add to those values? And what happens if one year is missed out completely?

Comment: Is 365 a constant offset or it can change? It isn't clear from your example and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a generator:

```
l = [140, 141, 145, 270, 365, 365.90, 1, 2, 5, 360, 1]

def wrap_at_365(it):
    # The number of wraps that have been found.
    wraps = 0
    it = iter(it)
    # Get the first item
    last = next(it)
    yield last
    for item in it:
        # Identify a wrap by checking if the next item is smaller than the previous
        if item < last:
            wraps += 1
        yield item + 365 * wraps
        last = item
```

It can be immediatly cast to a `list`:

```
>>> list(wrap_at_365(l))
[140, 141, 145, 270, 365, 365.9, 366, 367, 370, 725, 731]
```

On my computer it takes roughly 0.5s to convert a list containing 1 million numbers.

---

However to identify the number of times you need to be careful. I checked that the last item is bigger than the current one but what if it's 100 in year 1 and the next item represents 110 in year2? That will go undetected and I don't actually know how to detect that. Does your data contain some more details? And what about leap-years?

Comment: all my data roughly comes in same form. starts off at about the 140th day of year 1, and ends just before the 365th day of year two. the function you gave worked perfectly, thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the data from a file, then you should try operating on smaller sections of the file at a time. As you are processing the data, append the output to an outfile. For example, read the first 1000 lines of the file. Process them and then write them to the outfile. Then continue to the next 1000 lines. This way, python doesn't need to keep all 900k lines in memory. The lines that were previously processed will get garbage collected.